# Form Validation - Email, Name and Signature

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up a form with validation. I am able to make sure that the user fills in their name and email before sending, this validation works fine but I have not yet managed to make sure that the signaturepad is not empty on submission. 
The form will submit fine with or without a signature

I need the form to not allow submission without a signature present

Form:

```
<body>
    <div id="product_sheet" style="background:white;">
        <div class="poddeets col-xs-12" id="element">
            <div class="podlogo col-xs-4 col-md-12">
                <img src="https://website.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="150px" height="150px" style="text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -moz-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;" border="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
                    <div class="podfrom">
                        <h3>from:</h3>
                        <h4>Company Name</h4>
                        <p>Address Line 1<p>
                        <p>Address Line 2<p>
                        <p>Postcode<p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-0">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
                <div class="podto">
                        <h3>To</h3>
                        <h4>Company Name</h4>
                        <p>Address Line 1<p>
                        <p>Address Line 2<p>
                        <p>Postcode<p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="podcons">
            <h3>Items<h3>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pallet</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Pallets of Pipe</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Box</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Fixings</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="pdfcontact-form">
            <form  id="form" method="post" action="/" name="pdf-download">
                <div class="podrecieved">
                    <h3>Recieved by<h3>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label for="firstname">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label for="email_id">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email_id" class="form-control" id="email_id" name="email_id">
                </div>
                <div>                 
                    <label for="messages">
                        <span class="required">Additional Comments:</span> 
                        <textarea id="messages" name="messages" placeholder="Please write your message here." tabindex="5"></textarea> 
                    </label>  
                </div>   
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 sig">
                                    <h3>Click to sign</h3>
                                    <input type="text" id="pdftxt" name="signature" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="editor"></div>  
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="pdfsubmit">Submit POD</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Signature jQuery:

```
`<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var sign = $('#pdftxt').SignaturePad({
            allowToSign: true,
            img64: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
            border: '1px solid #c7c8c9',
            width: '300px',
            height: '150px',
            callback: function (data, action) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    })
</script>

<script>
//sketch lib
(function () {
var __slice = [].slice;

(function ($) {
    var Sketch;
    $.fn.sketch = function () {
        var args, key, sketch;
        key = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
        if (this.length > 1) {
            $.error('Sketch.js can only be called on one element at a time.');
        }
        sketch = this.data('sketch');
        if (typeof key === 'string' && sketch) {
            if (sketch[key]) {
                if (typeof sketch[key] === 'function') {
                    return sketch[key].apply(sketch, args);
                } else if (args.length === 0) {
                    return sketch[key];
                } else if (args.length === 1) {
                    return sketch[key] = args[0];
                }
            } else {
                return $.error('Sketch.js did not recognize the given command.');
            }
        } else if (sketch) {
            return sketch;
        } else {
            this.data('sketch', new Sketch(this.get(0), key));
            return this;
        }
    };
    Sketch = (function () {

        function Sketch(el, opts) {
            this.el = el;
            this.canvas = $(el);
            this.context = el.getContext('2d');
            this.options = $.extend({
                toolLinks: true,
                defaultTool: 'marker',
                defaultColor: '#000000',
                defaultSize: 2
            }, opts);
            this.painting = false;
            this.color = this.options.defaultColor;
            this.size = this.options.defaultSize;
            this.tool = this.options.defaultTool;
            this.actions = [];
            this.action = [];
            this.canvas.bind('click mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave mouseout touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', this.onEvent);
            if (this.options.toolLinks) {
                $('body').delegate("a[href=\"#" + (this.canvas.attr('id')) + "\"]", 'click', function (e) {
                    var $canvas, $this, key, sketch, _i, _len, _ref;
                    $this = $(this);
                    $canvas = $($this.attr('href'));
                    sketch = $canvas.data('sketch');
                    _ref = ['color', 'size', 'tool'];
                    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                        key = _ref[_i];
                        if ($this.attr("data-" + key)) {
                            sketch.set(key, $(this).attr("data-" + key));
                        }
                    }
                    if ($(this).attr('data-download')) {
                        sketch.download($(this).attr('data-download'));
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }

        Sketch.prototype.download = function (format) {
            var mime;
            format || (format = "png");
            if (format === "jpg") {
                format = "jpeg";
            }
            mime = "image/" + format;
            return window.open(this.el.toDataURL(mime));
        };

        Sketch.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
            this[key] = value;
            return this.canvas.trigger("sketch.change" + key, value);
        };

        Sketch.prototype.startPainting = function () {
            this.painting = true;
            return this.action = {
                tool: this.tool,
                color: this.color,
                size: parseFloat(this.size),
                events: []
            };
        };


        Sketch.prototype.stopPainting = function () {
            if (this.action) {
                this.actions.push(this.action);
            }
            this.painting = false;
            this.action = null;
            return this.redraw();
        };

        Sketch.prototype.onEvent = function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.targetTouches) {
                e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
                e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
            }
```

`$.sketch.tools[$(this).data('sketch').tool].onEvent.call($(this).data('sketch'), e);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            };`

```
        Sketch.prototype.redraw = function () {
            var sketch;
            //this.el.width = this.canvas.width();
            this.context = this.el.getContext('2d');
            sketch = this;
            $.each(this.actions, function () {
                if (this.tool) {
                    return 
$.sketch.tools[this.tool].draw.call(sketch, this);
                }
            });
            if (this.painting && this.action) {
                return 
$.sketch.tools[this.action.tool].draw.call(sketch, this.action);
            }
        };

        return Sketch;

    })();
    $.sketch = {
        tools: {}
    };
    $.sketch.tools.marker = {
        onEvent: function (e) {
            switch (e.type) {
                case 'mousedown':
                case 'touchstart':
                    if (this.painting) {
                        this.stopPainting();
                    }
                    this.startPainting();
                    break;
                case 'mouseup':
                    //return this.context.globalCompositeOperation = oldcomposite;
                case 'mouseout':
                case 'mouseleave':
                case 'touchend':
                    //this.stopPainting();
                case 'touchcancel':
                    this.stopPainting();
            }
            if (this.painting) {
                this.action.events.push({
                    x: e.pageX - this.canvas.offset().left,
                    y: e.pageY - this.canvas.offset().top,
                    event: e.type
                });
                return this.redraw();
            }
        },
        draw: function (action) {
            var event, previous, _i, _len, _ref;
            this.context.lineJoin = "round";
            this.context.lineCap = "round";
            this.context.beginPath();
            this.context.moveTo(action.events[0].x, action.events[0].y);
            _ref = action.events;
            for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                event = _ref[_i];
                this.context.lineTo(event.x, event.y);
                previous = event;
            }
            this.context.strokeStyle = action.color;
            this.context.lineWidth = action.size;
            return this.context.stroke();
        }
    };
    return $.sketch.tools.eraser = {
        onEvent: function (e) {
            return $.sketch.tools.marker.onEvent.call(this, e);
        },
        draw: function (action) {
            var oldcomposite;
            oldcomposite = this.context.globalCompositeOperation;
            this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
            action.color = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
            $.sketch.tools.marker.draw.call(this, action);
            return this.context.globalCompositeOperation = oldcomposite;
        }
    };
    })(jQuery);

}).call(this);


(function ($) {
    $.fn.SignaturePad = function (options) {

    //update the settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        allowToSign: true,
        img64: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
        border: '1px solid #c7c8c9',
        width: '300px',
        height: '150px',
        callback: function () {
            return true;
        }
    }, options);

    //control should be a textbox
    //loop all the controls
    var id = 0;

    //add a very big pad
    var big_pad = $('#signPadBig');
    var back_drop = $('#signPadBigBackDrop');
    var canvas = undefined;
    if (big_pad.length == 0) {

        back_drop = $('<div>')
        back_drop.css('position', 'fixed');
        back_drop.css('top', '0');
        back_drop.css('right', '0');
        back_drop.css('bottom', '0');
        back_drop.css('left', '0');
        back_drop.css('z-index', '1040 !important');
        back_drop.css('background-color', '#000');
        back_drop.css('display', 'none');
        back_drop.css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=50)');
        back_drop.css('opacity', '0.5');
        $('body').append(back_drop);

        big_pad = $('<div>');
        big_pad.css('display', 'none');
        big_pad.css('position', 'fixed');
        big_pad.css('margin', '0 auto');
        big_pad.css('top', '0');
        big_pad.css('bottom', '0');
        big_pad.css('right', '0');
        big_pad.css('left', '0');
        big_pad.css('z-index', '1000002 !important');
        big_pad.css('overflow', 'hidden');
        big_pad.css('outline', '0');
        big_pad.css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');

        big_pad.css('right', '0');
        big_pad.css('border', '1px solid #c8c8c8');
        big_pad.css('padding', '15px');
        big_pad.css('background-color', 'white');
        big_pad.css('margin-top', '15px');
        big_pad.css('width', '95%');
        big_pad.css('height', '90%');
        big_pad.css('border-radius', '10px');
        big_pad.attr('id', 'signPadBig');
        $('body').append(big_pad);

        var update_canvas_size = function () {
            var w = big_pad.width() //* 0.95;
            var h = big_pad.height() - 55;

            canvas.attr('width', w);
            canvas.attr('height', h);
        }


        canvas = $('<canvas>');
        canvas.css('display', 'block');
        canvas.css('margin', '0 auto');
        canvas.css('border', '1px solid #c8c8c8');
        canvas.css('border-radius', '10px');
        //canvas.css('width', '90%');
        //canvas.css('height', '80%');
        big_pad.append(canvas);

        update_canvas_size();
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            update_canvas_size();
        });

        var clearCanvas = function () {
            canvas.sketch().action = null;
            canvas.sketch().actions = [];       // this line empties the actions. 
            var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas[0].width, canvas[0].height);
            return true
        }

        var _get_base64_value = function () {
            var text_control = $.data(big_pad[0], 'control');  //settings.control; // $('#' + big_pad.attr('id'));
            return $(text_control).val();
        }

        var copyCanvas = function () {
            //get data from bigger pad
            var sigData = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");

            var _img = new Image;
            _img.onload = resizeImage;
            _img.src = sigData;

            var targetWidth = canvas.width();
            var targetHeight = canvas.height();

            function resizeImage() {
                var imageToDataUri = function (img, width, height) {

                    // create an off-screen canvas
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    // set its dimension to target size
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;

                    // draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                    // encode image to data-uri with base64 version of compressed image
                    return canvas.toDataURL();
                }

                var newDataUri = imageToDataUri(this, targetWidth, targetHeight);
                var control_img = $.data(big_pad[0], 'img');
                if (control_img)
                    $(control_img).attr("src", newDataUri);

                var text_control = $.data(big_pad[0], 'control');  //settings.control; // $('#' + big_pad.attr('id'));
                if (text_control)
                    $(text_control).val(newDataUri);
            }
        }

        var buttons = [
             {
                 title: 'Close',
                 callback: function () {
                     clearCanvas();
                     big_pad.slideToggle(function () {
                         back_drop.hide('fade');
                     });

                 }
             },
             {
                 title: 'Clear',
                 callback: function () {
                     clearCanvas();
                     if (settings.callback)
                         settings.callback(_get_base64_value(), 'clear');
                 }
             },
             {
                 title: 'Accept',
                 callback: function () {
                     copyCanvas();
                     clearCanvas();
                     big_pad.slideToggle(function () {
                         back_drop.hide('fade', function () {
                             if (settings.callback)
                                 settings.callback(_get_base64_value(), 'accept');
                         });
                     });
                 }
             }].forEach(function (e) {
                 var btn = $('<button>');
                 btn.attr('type', 'button');
                 btn.css('border', '1px solid #c8c8c8');
                 btn.css('background-color', 'white');
                 btn.css('padding', '10px');
                 btn.css('display', 'block');
                 btn.css('margin-top', '15px');
                 btn.css('margin-right', '5px');
                 btn.css('cursor', 'pointer');
                 btn.css('border-radius', '5px');
                 btn.css('float', 'right');
                 btn.css('height', '40px');
                 btn.text(e.title);
                 btn.on('click', function () {
                     e.callback(e.title);
                 })
                 big_pad.append(btn);

             });

    }
    else {
        canvas = big_pad.find('canvas')[0];
    }

    //init the signpad
    if (canvas) {
        var sign1big = $(canvas).sketch({ defaultColor: "#000", defaultSize: 5 });
    }

    //for each control
    return this.each(function () {

        var control = $(this);
        control.hide();

        //get the control parent
        var wrapper = control.parent();
        var img = $('<img>');

        //style it
        img.css("cursor", "pointer");
        img.css("border", settings.border);
        img.css("height", settings.height);
        img.css("width", settings.width);
        img.css('border-radius', '5px')
        img.attr("src", settings.img64);

        if (typeof (wrapper) == 'object') {
            wrapper.append(img);
        }




        //init the big sign pad
        if (settings.allowToSign == true) {
            //click to the pad bigger
            img.on('click', function () {
                //show the pad
                back_drop.show();
                big_pad.slideToggle();

                //save control to use later
                $.data(big_pad[0], 'img', img);
                $.data(big_pad[0], 'control', control);

                //settings.control = control;
                //settings.img = img;
            });
        }
    });
};


})(jQuery);

</script>`
```

Validation jQuery:

```
jQuery( "#pdfsubmit" ).click(function() {
var $form = $("form[name='pdf-download']"),
    $successMsg = $(".alert");
$.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/);
});
jQuery.validator.addMethod("signature", function(value, element, options) {
    if( '#pdftxt'.isEmpty()){
            return false;            
        }
    return true;
}, "Your signature is required");
$form.validate({    
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            letters: true
        },
        email_id: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messagess: {
        firstname: "Please specify your name (only letters and spaces are allowed)",
        email_id: "Please specify a valid email address"
    },
});
```

Any help validating that there is a signature present before submission would be great

Comment: tried to just add the 'required' attribute to the signature input?

Comment: @AugustoM yeah ive tried that but doesnt make a difference. the signature is not text its a base64 object and the required attribute doesnt seem to work with that :-(